# Keyerror that occurs only in one dev environment

Tags: python, django

I ran into a strange problem.... I have the following code that works perfectly fine in my local development , but when I use the same in project dev server, I get a KeyError: 'firstname'
Either I am missing something very silly here, or something that I have no clue of .

```
def register(self,request, **kwargs):


        try:    
            data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
            print data
            print " reached register"
            email = data['email']
            password = data['password']
            firstname = data['firstName']
            lastname = data['lastName']
            newdata = {'email' : email , 'password1': password , 'password2':password, 'firstname':firstname , 'lastname':lastname }
```

The log output is the following:

```
[Wed Jul 31 21:42:24 2013] [error] {u'lastName': u'Adams', u'password': u'pass', u'email': u'samad@g.com', u'firstName': u'Sam'}
[Wed Jul 31 21:42:24 2013] [error]  reached register
[Wed Jul 31 21:42:24 2013] [error] ERROR:root:'firstname'
[Wed Jul 31 21:42:24 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 31 21:42:24 2013] [error]   File "/home/ubuntu/djangoEC/userdetails/api.py", line 102, in register
[Wed Jul 31 21:42:24 2013] [error]     firstname = data['firstName']
[Wed Jul 31 21:42:24 2013] [error] KeyError: 'firstname'
```

Phew, any ideas?

Comment: You have a `try` with no `except`. The code snippet you pasted is not valid.

Comment: What is `data`? Please give us output of `type(data)`. If your error log is correct, it is not an ordinary `dict`.

Comment: Depending on the Python versions running on your different systems the key error might be caused because you assign `data['firstName']`, which might be interpreted as a byte-string (non-unicode), while the key in data is actually a unicode string `data[u'firstName']`.
If you run different Python versions that might explain the inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: It could be some bizarre decoding error on a non-English machine. You should really be using u'firstName' so that you match the dict keys.

Comment: @tdelaney : that solved the problem. Strange that it did not occur in local env, but the unicode makes sense here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered by @tdelaney. Using data[u'firstName'] solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks up `'firstName'`, but the exception says `'firstname'`. Note the case. Either your real code says `'firstname'` in it (or your real data has `'firstname'` in it, or some other case mismatch error), or `data` is some weird dict-like object that lowercases keys on lookups. I suspect it's the first answer.